# no mails routed to/from new Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, exchange-migration

I have an Exchange Server 2003 up and running for years. Now I am in the mid of transition to Exchange Server 2010, I already installed it, put the latest Servicepack on it and everything seems fine, BUT: Mails do not get delivered to MailBoxes on the new Exchange 2010.

e.g. when I create a new mailbox on the old server, Emails in and out to/from it work like a charm. But as soon as I move it to the new server, emails get stuck. Noe delivered from outside or old mailboxes, not send out from the new server to enywhere. Sending between Mailboxes on the new Server of course is working.

I can see the connectors between old and new Server in the Exchange 2003 Admin Tool, but I cannot find these nowhere on the new server. 
I have also setup sending connectors at the new server to send out mails directly, but that does not work. In all other areas, the servers are perfectly working together - moving mailboxes between, seeing each other etc. "just" they dont exchange (!) any emails -

Any ideas what I missed?

I also followed the hints from:
[Upgrading from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010, routing works in one direction only](https://serverfault.com/questions/309750/upgrading-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010-routing-works-in-one-direction-on) 
There Emails were transported at least in one direction, in my case they are not transported at all.
Both my connectors are up and valid abd have the correct source/target shown on 
Get-RoutingGroupConnector | FL

Kind regards

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Was similar problem as with question cited above, there was also a smarthost in use (Apache James) and one mailet with unexpected behaviour. I upgraded to new version of James, moved this to the same machine as the new exchange server runs; then removed all connectors from old exchange servers and added just the routinggroup connectors back. Now works fine.